# Issue training model in ML.net. Issue changing model from TaxiFareExample. 'Features' must be a known-size vector of R4, but has type: Vec<I4, 2>

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

Issue training model in ML.net.

> Issue changing model from TaxiFareExample. 'Features' must be a
>   known-size vector of R4, but has type: Vec.

I started with the `TaxiFare` Example and that works. But then I changed the model and added my own values and my data. I got the error about the `Features` above. I played with it for a while and tried limiting my data. Even tried predicting the Fare Amount again but using my values as the model (2 integers).

My data model is very basic, I won't to add more variables but was trying to start simple.

Some of the first lines (I am getting the first two values as `int`'s and trying to predict the third as a `float`).

```
0,2,17.5

0,7,8

0,7,8.5
```

Asked a question [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/533) but haven't seen a response yet.

Comment: Please provide code. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: ML.Net might only support floats in this case, as mentioned in one of the tutorials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/taxi-fare

Comment: I copied the sample code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis. Got the same issue. I don't know how to fix..tried to replace the TextFeaturizer but didnt work.

Comment: Your problem is with the data type, just only float type and see if it works. As I mentioned in the 3rd point of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I was also getting the same exception and I found that :**

1. You have to have a mandatory column named '**Label**' in your input data class.

> Something like [**this**](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/machine-learning-and-ai/get-started-with-ml-dotnet-tutorial) example.
>
> > *When the model is trained and evaluated, by default, the values in the*
> >     *Label column is considered as correct values to be predicted.*

2. Or, You have to use the `ColumnCopier` like [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/taxi-fare#load-and-transform-data), if you don't want to have the mandatory column named '**Label**'.
3. And, preferably all the numeric values should be of type **float** (or **string** which has to be vectorized). Or According to [**this**](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/IDataViewTypeSystem.md#standard-column-types).

   > The names I4 and R4 means `int` and `float` for the purposes of data view type system.